# ImportError: No module named __main__ (Python 2.7 & Pickle)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

So on my game I'm making, I'm trying to load the data files needed for the game, and when I load the file with pickle (The file has been loaded, I've double-checked that.) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/Deeper-master/Deeper.py", line 257, in <module>
    tutorialData = pickle.load(tutorialFile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1075, in load_inst
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named __main__
```

I saw a question like this on Stack Overflow, but it's a little different than my situation, so sorry if this is a duplicate, I'm just trying to figure it out.

You can find my code [here](http://github.com/OrionDark7/Deeper). The main script is Deeper.py, just to save time.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice in your repo, you have a `Deeper.pyc` and `Deeper.py`. If I run `Deeper.py`, it raises the same exception as yours. If I run `Deeper.pyc`, it raises another exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Deeper.py", line 7, in <module>
    ToolbarTile = pygame.image.load("ToolbarTile.png")
pygame.error: Couldn't open Toolbar Tile.png
```

So, the code (bytecode, some previous version) references `ToolbarTile.png`, but the exception is about `Toolbar Tile.png` (with a space). So I changed the file name to account for that.

Now it raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Deeper.py", line 766, in <module>
    else:
  File "Deeper.py", line 394, in __init__
    def displayCraft(self):
pygame.error: Couldn't open options.png
```

There's an `Options.png` in your files, but it looks for `options.png` (lower case) (even your new code in Deeper.py looks for that). So I changed that.

Now it works, albeit with `Deeper.pyc` so that must be why you thought:

> (The file has been loaded, I've double-checked that.)

Maybe delete the `Deeper.pyc` and do a git-bisect to see when the bug was introduced (ps: check your toolbar.dat, does it seem okay to you? Also check the way you're using pickle.load. Maybe you should use `rb` instead of `r`?)